# Magento - Duplicated live site to a development server but it redirects to live site?

Tags: magento, redirect, migration

I hope you can help get to the bottom of this. This is whats happened:

- We duplicated our live Magento site (for example we'll call it domain1.com) to a development server (for this example I'll call this domain2.com)
- Did a find/replace for the domain1.com to domain2.com in both the database and files
- Deleted all var/cache and var/session files
- Reindexed all indexes via SSH
- Emptied browser cache
- Checked all file permissions
- Disabled the .htaccess incase this was causing a redirect

But it's still redirecting to the live server (domain1.com)??

Any ideas what may be triggering this?

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: My guesses would be, that you either missed a `%base_url%` value in table `core_config_data`, or your `app/etc/local.xml` still points to the live database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue...hopefully this helps some other people.

When the site was duplicated we edited the "local.xml" file with the new details but kept the old one and renamed it "localnew.xml"

It seems Magento was still picking up these details as so was redirecting to the old site.

**Deleting the "localnew.xml" (or whatever you called it eg. localxxx.xml) fixed all our issues!**

Comment: that doesn't seem to make any sense. Magento shouldn't have any reason to look at every randomly named file and parse its contents. The problem I've seen is that old address urls still sit in the MySQL database and you have to update those before everything will work right at the new url. You said you fixed that, I know. But again, why would Magento be parsing random files??? Maybe it looks for local*.xml. I wonder what happens if you rename it to abc.def

Comment: i know, doesn't make sense at all! The development database was 100% clean of the old URL which is what was confusing me. renamed it to abcd.xml and it doesn't parse, also renamed to localn.xml and it didnt parse...so must be if two files called local*.xml are in that directory it parses the longer one? crazy...

Comment: very weird. It's probably part of some weird code hidden deep in the core somewhere.

Comment: i've done everything you did before I got to this post -- but it is STILL not working... only one %local%.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in a local Centos 6.4 running in a VM at the moment to test various things.

My production Magento site is in that folder: **/var/www/html/magento**
and the staging site is there: **/var/www/html/staging/magento**

I had the same issue than you, did everything I could come up with, triple checked the urls in the database, cleared the cache, checked the .htaccess file, rebooted multiple times.

The one thing that fixed the issue has been to set back the permissions properly:

```
cd /var/www/html/staging/magento
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chown -R sysadmin:apache .
chmod -R 777 media app/etc var var/.htaccess
```

Answer (score -2):

Just open your DB and open the table "core_config_data"

then edit the values for the path  web/secure/base_url & web/unsecure/base_url

Comment: Thanks for the obvious post, but I mentioned I'd already done this, and I've posted the answer also.